# JSF's facelets and AngularJS ng-view

Tags: angularjs, jsf, facelets

I'm inside my `view.xthml` which has `facelets` component in there. Like:

```
<ui:composition template="/layout.xhtml"> .. whatever
```

Being there I try to integrate `AngualerJS`, putting `ng-view`, like this:

```
   <div ng-view> </div>
```

When my `/view.jsf` is rendering I got server side error:

```
Attribute name "ng-view" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

So, it validates my `html` that prevents angular `ng-view` to start working.

The question is: how to integrate `angularjs` and its `ng-view` with `jsf/facelets` based on my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facelets is a [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml) based view technology which uses XHTML to generate HTML output. In XML, each element attribute **must** have a value.

You can indeed assign it an empty string as value, but `ng-view="true"` or `ng-view="ng-view"` would be more self-documenting, keeping `checked="checked"` and `selected="selected"` in mind.

```
<div ng-view="true">
```

Comment: you are right. If use <div ng-view=""> then "smart" JSF transforms it to "<div></div>"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-view = "">
```

Looks not nice but it works for me on that stage (of getting rid of `jsf`).